# Не могу понять, почему Google Play не одобряет приложение Android TV

Tags: android, android-sdk, google-play

Google Play присылает такое сообщение

1. Non-full screen static banner ads
   Your app displays static banner ads which are not full screen. Please refer to our Functionality documentation.
2. Ads not interact-able with D-pad
   Your app displays ads which cannot be dismissed using the D-pad or gamepad controller. Please refer to our D-pad Navigation documentation for more information.

В Manifest у меня указан android:banner="@drawable/app_logo", размер картинки 320 x 180 px (Как написано в документации https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start#banner)

Причина второго пункта мне так же непонятна, все управление сделан в соответствии с guidelines, в приложении используются только стандартные элементы и паттерны

Если кто встречался с подобной проблемой напишите как решали или что может я не так понимаю?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что в этом случае надо обращатся в службу поддержки.

Comment: У вас с рекламным баннером беда.

Comment: В документации написано не про рекламный баннер. По второму вопросу тоже все понятно - рекламный баннер невозможно убрать. А какие там элементы управления используются совершенно неважно.

Comment: 1.статическая реклама не на весь экран. 2.реклама не убирается с помошью D-pad

Comment: Но рекламы в приложении нету